# How to make typedef type accessible in multiple files?

Tags: haxe

typedef has great benefits, but I don't know how to include the same type in multiple files is haxe?
for example I need to use this type in a.hx and b.hx files:

```
typedef JsonControl = {
    var name:String;
    var type:String;
    var user_answer:String;
    var answer:Array<String>;
    var htmlID:String;
}
```

how to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works like a regular class definition, so preferably you would define a package and save it as a .hx file. Then simply import it where you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

As another answer states, the rules for how haxe discovers typedefs is identical to how it finds classes.

### Type-Named Module Files

The easiest way to share a type between multiple files in Haxe is to create a module named after that type. For example, suppose you are in package `x` and want to access the type `MyType` from multiple files. You would create the file `x/MyType.hx` and place `MyType`’s definition in `x/MyType.hx`. This file might look like this:

```
package x;

typedef MyType = {
    id:String,
}
```

### Module Sub-Types

If you want, you may place `MyType` in a differently-named file such as `x/MySharedTypes.hx`. If you do that, accessing it takes more work. To consume it in another file, you either need to have an `import x.MySharedTypes` statement or type the module-qualified name `x.MySharedTypes.MyType` (from a file in package `x`, you only need to type `MySharedTypes.MyType`). In this example, you might have:

`x/MySharedTypes.hx`:

```
package x;

typedef MyType = {
    id:String,
}
```

`x/MyFirstConsumer.hx`:

```
package x;

import x.MySharedTypes;

class MyFirstConsumer {
    var instance:MyType;
}
```

`x/MySecondConsumer.hx`:

```
package x;

class MySecondConsumer {
    var instance:MySharedTypes.MyType;
}
```

## Documentation

You may read further details in  the page titled [Module Sub-Types](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-module-sub-types.html) in the manual.